# How to root Lava Iris 60?

Tags: rooting

I have Lava Iris 60 running on Android 7.0 Nougat with Mediatek MT6737m chipset. I'm trying to root this phone.

I have tried many PC software for rooting, but none of them work. I have tried to unlock the bootloader, but it is not working. I have installed all MTK drivers. In cmd, it's not recognizing the fastboot device.

How to root Lava Iris 60?

Answer (score 0):

To root the Lava Iris Fuel, you must disconnect your device from the Internet and then use **Kingroot**. You can download Kingroot and find more detailed instructions on the official [**Kingroot XDA thread**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/one-click-root-tool-android-2-x-5-0-t3107461).